# can't send email using xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I cant send email when uses xampp server.
here is my code.

```
    class email {

        function emailwithattach($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message)
        {

            $email_message="Test mail";
            $email_subject = "Transaction Detail Notification";

            $headers = "From: ".$email_from;

            if (@mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
   }
```

its work using another web server but cant work in XAMPP

Comment: What happens if you remove `@` and let PHP inform you about error conditions?

Comment: no its not work after removing @ and it doesnt return error it works perfact but email cant receive in mailbox

Comment: You have to configure your smtp address etc in xamp php settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup mail setting on XAMPP in `php.ini` Ex. Authentication Username, Password,Po

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't have a mail server installed on your local. This code will very well work on webserver but not on localserver/localhost unless you have a mail server installed.

**[Source](http://thephpcode.blogspot.in/2009/03/setting-up-local-mail-smtp-pop3-imap.html)** : Setting up a mail server on localhost on **XAMPP**.

[**Here**](http://coded-words.tumblr.com/post/6936532107/configure-gmail-as-smtp-in-xampp-to-send-mail) is a beautiful tutorial how to setup gmail smtp on **XAMPP**.

Comment: You don't **need** to have it installed. I once managed to get it out by using my webserver's SMTP address and password by editing my `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SMTP Server and need to configure an SMTP server on localhost port 25 in `php.ini`file to work your mail function from the local system,else you need to put your code in webserver.